# Wordpress at root and vue in sub dir. Masking of vue with wordpress URL. URL points root and page load is of vue

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, vuejs3

At root there is WordPress site. And in subdirectory calles 'vue' there is vue build is there. In wordpress URL if 'podcaster' or 'crowd' is not a part of a URL then I want to load vue page without changing browser URL.

Below is my folder structure
[image]

```
Target is:

www.example.com/podcaster //display in the address bar, points to WP (var/www/html/)
www.example.com/crowd //display in the address bar, points to WP (var/www/html/)
www.example.com/username  //display in the address bar, points to VUE (var/www/html/vue)
www.example.com           //display in the address bar, points to WP (var/www/html/)
```

Below is the WordPress root directory `.htaccess`:

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    # The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
    # dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
    # Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            # Rewrite rule for vue
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/crowd/
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/podcaster/
                RewriteRule (.+) /vue/$1 [L]
        
            RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
            RewriteBase /
        
            RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
        
        </IfModule>
        
        # END WordPress
```

Below is vue sub directory `.htaccess`:

```
# /vue/.htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

Comment: So, what is the "problem" exactly? You've stated that "if 'podcaster' is not a part of a URL then I want to load vue", however, you've stated that `https://example.com` (which does not contain `podcaster`) should point to WordPress - please clarify. The directive you've posted implies "podcaster" is an entire URL-path segment (not simply that the URL contains "podcaster"), including a trailing slash. Where can "podcaster" occur in the URL? Literally _anywhere_? Is that the entire WordPress `.htaccess` file? What about the WP front-controller?

Comment: @MrWhite Thanks for your reply. Let me clarify the issue.
Root Wordpress .htaccess is same as default wordpress htaccess and in that just below RewriteEngine on there is below lines: 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/podcaster/
  RewriteRule (.+) /vue/$1 [L]

"https://example.com/podcaster/" and "https://example.com/" should points to Wordpress page and other then that like "https://example.com/monali"[visible in browser address bar] should points to vue [https://example.com/vue/monali ]

Comment: @MrWhite Thank you very much for your reply. I had try to clarify my issue in original question. Please review it and let me know if still it is not understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not stated exactly what the problem is, however...

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/podcaster/
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /vue/$1 [L,NC]
> ```

This will result in requests for the root being internally rewritten to the `/vue` subdirectory (I'm assuming you've placed this at the *top* of the WordPress `.htaccess` file in the root directory). You've stated that WordPress should be served from the root. In which case you should change the `RewriteRule` *pattern* from `.*` (0 or more) to `.+` (1 or more) to avoid being triggered for requests to the root (base URL / homepage).

You will also need to ensure that rewritten requests (by the WordPress front-controller - to `index.php` - in the code that follows) are not also rewritten (otherwise *everything* will ultimately be rewritten to the `/vue` subdirectory). We can do this by adding another *condition* that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable, which is *empty* on the initial request and set to `200` (as in 200 OK status) after the later rewrite.

**UPDATE:** And I suspect you also have a number of static resources (CSS, JS, images, etc) that also need to be excluded, so we probably need to add a filesystem check for those, so the request is not rewritten if it already maps to a file (or directory).

For example, bringing the above points together, this becomes:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/podcaster/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+) /vue/$1 [L]
```

I've removed the `NC` flag as that was superfluous here. Note also that the *condition* is successful when the string "/podcaster/" (note that slashes) does not appear *anywhere* in the URL-path. Should this not be restricted to the *start* of the URL-path perhaps? eg. `!^/podcaster/`.

Also, where is the rest of the WordPress `.htaccess` file? The WordPress front-controller (the part that normally appears after the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker) should appear *after* your custom directive. If you place your custom rewrite at the end of the WordPress `.htaccess` file, after the WP front-controller section then your directive will not doing anything since all requests will be routed to WordPress.

Note that you should place your custom directives *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker. You should never edit the code between the `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress` comments since this block of code is maintained by WordPress and your code could be overwritten when WP updates (unless you take additional steps to prevent this). There is no need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` or `<IfModule>` directives.

> Below is vue .htaccess which in "vue" sub directory
>
> ```
> <ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
>     RewriteEngine On
>   RewriteBase /vue/
>   RewriteRule ^vue/index\.html$ - [L]
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>   RewriteRule . /vue/index.html [L]
> </ifModule>
> ```

The Vue `.htaccess` file isn't quite right (although should work OK). The first `RewriteRule` directive (which is simply an optimisation) should not include the `vue` subdirectory in the regex. In other words, it should be written:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
```

Since the URL-path that is matched is relative to the filesystem path that contains the `.htaccess` file.

In fact, you can remove all instances of `vue` from this file (which makes it simpler and more portable), providing you also remove the `RewriteBase` directive entirely. For example:

```
# /vue/.htaccess

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

Relative substitution strings (ie. `index.html` in the 2nd `RewriteRule` directive above) are relative to the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file (providing you don't have a `RewriteBase` directive that states otherwise). So, the above naturally rewrites the request to `/vue/index.html` without having to explicitly state the directory.

Comment: Thank you very much for your concern. I had tried your solution but every url points to "vue" sub-directory only. My root .htaccess and 'vue' sub directory .htaccess is as mentioned in updated question.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, the WordPress front-controller rewrites requests to `index.php`, which will ultimately cause everything to be rewritten to `/vue` - unless we add another _condition_ to prevent this. You should also avoid editing the code inside the WordPress code block, since this is maintained by WP itself. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @MonaliBhagat Correction: Should be `REDIRECT_STATUS` (not `REQUEST_STATUS` as I had initially written). I've updated my answer.

Comment: @MonaliBhagat Actually, thinking about this... Presumably you have many static resources (CSS, JS, images, etc) that are associated with WordPress that must not be rewritten to the Vue site?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works for https://example.com/podcaster/ to redirect to WP but not for https://example.com. As https://example.com redirects to vue

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

This solve issue to redirect base url to WP

Comment: @MonaliBhagat Ok, that will prevent static resources (mentioned above) from being rewritten to the `/vue` subdirectory. However, it's not clear how that resolved the "base URL" issue, since the regex `.+` should have already resolved that. Anyway, glad you got it working. :)